# 403 error when making a service call

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've got a weird IIS issue I'm trying to work through.

We have an auth service running in our dev environment. When called inside our VPN, just on a browser via HTTP request, the auth service works fine. But, when I try to make the exact same service call from a website running on the same server as the auth service, I get a 403.

When I hit the URL directly, I get the correct xml response.

When I hit the exact same service call, IIS spits this into the log: --> 403 4 5 0

I'm kinda stumped on this. I'm wondering if the error might be because, in this case, the website making the service call and the auth website are different applications on the same website, and there's some kind of cross-auth error. I'm not sure.

When I make the service call in my dev website, I do fully qualify the domain. I make this same service call from a different website, even a different server, and have no problems. Again, naked request on a browser works fine too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may be worthwhile checking that there isn't an IP restriction in place within IIS, for example to deny connections from 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I'm not seeing a restriction in IIS Manager Permissions at the root node, but I'm not sure if I need to check anywhere else.

Comment: Are you looking in 'IP Address and Domain Restrictions'?

Comment: Yeah, there are no restrictions set at the root server node, the website level, or the application level.

Comment: I'm wondering if in the IIS logs, the 403 4 5 0 implies 403.4 has a substatus code, which would be an SSL required error.

Comment: Though that makes almost no sense if I can hit the URL via a normal browser request.

Comment: It depends on your logging settings - on my machine here, 403 4 5 0 would imply HTTP 403.4, with a Win32 status of 5 and a time taken of 0 milliseconds (the last two of which are unlikely).

Comment: Are you using Windows Authentication?

Comment: Try using Fiddler to capture the working and non-working requests and see what the difference is.